# STM32F334R8: ADC with DMA

Tags: stm32, dma, adc

Could someone provide me a basic code that just implements ADC with DMA for STM32 please ? I'd like to compare it to my solution that doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: There are examples of this is the stm32 cube package.

Answer (score 1):

How about this tutorial?
http://www.bepat.de/2020/11/27/stm32f103c8-adc-dual-regular-simultaneous-mode/

It describes how to use both ADCs of an F103C8 simultaneously with DMA.